# short keys for menu not working in wpf in prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

My application is developed using C# (WPF and Prism). It is having 4 projects in it and different regions for each project:

1. menu region contains menu view
2. Drawing Region contains drawings
3. Tree region contains tree view
4. Status Region contains satus view

I done binding of shortcut keys for menu and it works fine but for that I need to select a menu header first, for example if I want to open new dashBoard window on <kbd>CTRL+N</kbd>  first i need to select `New` Menu on the menu bar. If you have a look at other applications like Word, Notepad etc. if you press <kbd>CTR+N</kbd> it opens new file and you need not require to go at new menu.

Is it due to different regions in prism?

There is nothing wrong with the code. It is simple input binding code is something like this:

```
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="A"  Command="{Binding AddDashBoardCommand}">   
        </KeyBinding>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Is it due to when I press short keys `m` in different region `n` `m` expecting other region to respond? What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my understanding, it may be related to the focus on a particular region. Anyway, a possible solution that would work is by using ***Windows's InputBindings***, instead of defining the ***ShortKey*** on a specified **Region**.

This way, the `Input Binding` would take action anytime you would have focus on the **Window Application**, without needing to open the `New` menu. However, you would need to take into account that the ***Command Binding*** would yield on the **Shell's ViewModel**.

So, if you would need to delegate the action to a particular **ViewModel**, you could ***Publish()*** an `Event` through **EventAggregator**, which its type would depend on the action made by the user (*NewWindowEvent*, *CopyEvent*, *SaveEvent*, ...). And therefore, each corresponding **ViewModel** would then suscribe to the particular ***Event/s*** that it would only know how to handle it.

You should be able to use `InputBindings` with or without ***Modifiers*** attribute.

Regards.

Comment: yes. your approach is absolutely right!! its working thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am glad I help you. I would appreaciate you could mark the answer as correct so new incoming people with your same problem would know which answer was useful. Thanks for voting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use it as below:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding AddDashBoardCommand}">   
    </KeyBinding>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

So, using above (*added Modifiers property*): shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> should work for `Add Dashboard` command.

BTW, I would recommend *changing* your Add Dashboard shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, as <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> is already used for selecting all text.

Comment: this is not what i wanted.binding is fine but problem is with focus as there are multiple regions.i want the menu to be in focus always like the menu of visual studio or any other application.so that if i press ctr+n it should open new window for adding dashboard.